# _delete_by_query contains unrecognized parameter

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am upgrading elasticsearch 5.6 to 7 along with `spring-data-elasticsearch` (to 4.12). I am using `ElasticsearchRepository` to `deleteAll` documents.

```
@Repository
public interface WhateverContentRepository extends IContentRepository<WhateverContent> {
}
```

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface IContentRepository<T> extends ElasticsearchRepository<T, String> {
}
```

The error I get while deleting all documents in `whateverContentIndex` is

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=request [/whateverContentIndex/_delete_by_query] contains unrecognized parameters: [allow_no_indices], [conflicts], [expand_wildcards], [ignore_throttled], [ignore_unavailable], [requests_per_second], [slices], [wait_for_completion]]
```

I confirmed that index did have data to delete. The workaround of dropping and re-creating the index works.

My hunch is that probably I am missing a plugin? Over the course of testing with in memory ES I ended up importing these `Netty4Plugin.class, CommonAnalysisPlugin.class, ParentJoinPlugin.class`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which Elasticseacrh version are you using and how do you access it? What do you mean by in-memory ES?

Comment: By in memory i mean embedded elastic. Earlier I was using `api 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.12.1'` and 
    `api 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.2.1'` but downgrading these to `api 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.11.2'` and 
   ` api 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.1.10'` worked. It seems like its the problem of the plugin compatibility with the latest es versions. And unfortunately we are still using embedded elastic for testing

Comment: We stopped using starting Elasticsearch nodes for testing Spring Data Elasticsearch, because this plugin stuff is error-prone and hard to maintain. I strongly recommend to switch to use TestContainers